# Guzzle 6 Async request return Argument 1 passed must be of the type array, string given,

Tags: laravel, guzzle, guzzle6

I'm trying to make an asynchronous POST call, but guzzle call returns the following error:

" **ErrorException in Request.php line 220:
Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::__construct() must be of the type array, string given, called in C:\Program Files ...\app\Http\Controllers\ConfirmAccountController.php on line 87 and defined** "

In ConfirmAccountController:

```
$client = new Client(['base_uri' => 'correct_api_address']);

$request = new Request('POST', 'testpromoboiler/updateUser',  [
        'query' => ['token' => $user->sdg_token ,
                    'address' => $user->address ,
                  ]
    ]);

$promise = $client->sendAsync($request)->then(function ($response) {
    echo 'I completed! ' . $response->getBody();
});

$promise->wait();
```

Why I get this error?

I have done two other synchronous calls and everything went well.

Thanks

Comment: In `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request` the first 2 parameters are arrays. First is the GET parameters and the second is the POST parameters. Not sure what `Client` object refers to in your code, but you should probably add the method and the URL there, not in the request object.

Answer (score 3):

That code instantiates Laravel frameworks `Request` class.

Use guzzles request method instead:

```
$request = $client->request('POST', 'testpromoboiler/updateUser',  [
        'query' => ['token' => $user->sdg_token ,
                    'address' => $user->address ,
                  ]
    ]);
```